# django remove line break from textarea python

Tags: python, django, html, tinymce, textarea

i have a text area tha is [tinymce application](http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/full.php) that devolve the text introduce in html.
so if i introduce this:
I, this is an example.
that i recive,`<p> I, this is an example.</p>`
in my view i remove the html tags, and if the tag are "`p`" than replace for an`\n`.
result:`I, this is an example.\n`
but if i introduce this:

I,

this is an example.

this return:

```
<p> I,</p>
<p>this is an example.</p>
```

result:

```
I,\n
this is an example.\n
```

I want to remove the line break, so the result are:I,\n this is an example.\n

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend fixing the `<p>` tag issue on the client side, as you can configure tinymce not to use `<p>` tags at all:

```
tinyMCE.init({
        ...
        forced_root_block : false
});
```

http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:forced_root_block